# Meter eventos de un calendario a una base de datos xampp

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

A ver como consigo explicar esto bien sin meter todo el codigo por que seria una locura. El error que me da en la consola es este: jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2     POST http://localhost/Proyecto/Codigo/php/calendario/insertarDatosGabe_Newell.php 404 (Not Found).
Tengo estas dos funciónes:

```
function requestDB(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'../../php/calendario/pedirDatosGabe_Newell.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      $.each(response, function(index, object){
        var fecha = object.fecha;
        var horaInicio = object.horaInicio;
        var horaFin = object.horaFin;
        var nombre = object.nombre;
        var descripcion = object.descripcion;
        $('#IDdestino').append('<li>' + fecha + ' - ' + horaInicio + ' - ' + horaFin + ' - ' + nombre + ' - ' + descripcion +'</li>');
      });
    },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
  }
```

```
function crearEvento() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '../../php/calendario/insertarDatosGabe_Newell.php',
      data: {
        fechaEvento: fecha,
        horaInicio: horaInicio,
        horaFin: horaFin,
        nombre: nombre,
        descripcion: descripcion
      },
      success: function (response) {
        if (response == 1) {
          agregarEvento(fecha, horaInicio, horaFin, nombre, descripcion);
          alert("Evento Creado");
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  };
```

Aparte tengo estas dos:

Esta me guarda el evento en el array.

```
const agregarEvento = (fecha, horaInicio, horaFin, nombre, descripcion) => {
 eventos.push({
   date: new Date(fecha + 'T' + horaInicio + 'T'  + horaFin),
   text: `${nombre}: ${descripcion}`
 });
}
```

```
function guardarEvento() {
 crearEvento(fecha, horaInicio, horaFin, nombre, descripcion);
 cerrarFormulario();
 generateCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear); // Actualizar el calendario con los nuevos eventos
}
```

de php para conectar la base de datos, pedir los datos e insertar tengo esto,

```
<?php
require("conectarGabe_Newel.php");

$fechaEvento = $_POST["fechaEvento"];
$HoraInicioEvento = $_POST["horaInicio"];
$HoraFinEvento = $_POST["horaFin"];
$NombreEvento = $_POST["nombre"];
$DescripcionEvento = $_POST["descripcion"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO eventos (fechaEvento, horaInicio, horaFin, nombre, descripcion)
VALUES ('$fechaEvento', '$HoraInicioEvento', '$HoraFinEvento', '$NombreEvento', '$DescripcionEvento')";
mysqli_query ($conexion, $sql);

echo 1;

?>
```

Esta inserta los datos.

```
<?php
require("conectarGabe_Newel.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM eventos";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

$eventos = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $eventos[] = $row;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($eventos);
?>
```

Esta pide los datos.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "calendario";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

?>
```

Y esta conecta con la base de datos.

No sé si será suficiente documentación. No se por donde tirar ya.

Os dejo la estructura de la base de datos en una foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En que path tiene ubicados el script que tiene la funcion requestDB y los scripts php?, porque al hacer una llamada de este tipo '../../php/calendario/pedirDatosGabe_Newell.php' lo que haces es ir dos directorios atrás de donde esta ubicado el script que invoca, por eso se pierde.

Comment: C:\Users\xus_x\Desktop\Proyecto\Codigo\php\calendario Dentro de esa carpeta calendario esta los php la conexion, insertar y pedir

Comment: Es que `Desktop`no es el sitio donde deben estar tus archivos. Compara la ruta del mensaje de error `http://localhost/Proyecto/Codigo/php/calendario/insertarDatosGabe_Newell.php` con la ruta que acabas de decir: `C:\Users\xus_x\Desktop\Proyecto\Codigo\php\calendario` Por eso no encuentra los archivos. Debes ponerlos dentro del directorio `htdocs`de XAMPP.

Comment: La he puesto en htdocs y sigue sin funcionar: C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\Codigo\html\calendario

Comment: ¿Qué error da ahora? ¿Qué estás escribiendo en la barra del navegador para probar tu código?